# Filename without extension in nginx SCRIPT_FILENAME

Tags: nginx

I serve both `php` and executable files via `nginx`. Thus, I separate the by the extension of request URL as

```
location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ \.c$ {
fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
fastcgi_index  index;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

With `PHP`, the script to run has `.php` extension; but for executable files, `.hello.c` is the original script and its compiled executable is `hello` file.

I need to run the `hello` file when visiting `https://example.com/hello.c`.

Is there any directive in nginx instead of `$fastcgi_script_name` to get the script name without extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture it in the location.

For example:

```
location ~ ^(.*)\.c$ {
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    fastcgi_index  index;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$1;
}
```